# How to remove the icon from notification or any alternative to change wallpaper

Tags: desktop-background

I'd like my Desktop to have dynamic wallpaper which change after every few minutes.

I use `wally` to achieve this. No doubt `wally` is great in its work, but one thing that I don't like is the `wally` icon in the notification area which is useless for me.

Once triggered there is no need for any monitoring, or any other task to be done, as I just want a flawless wallpaper changer.

Is there a way I can remove the `wally` icon from the notification area, or suggestions on any other application which does the same work but does not use the notification area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't try wally, but CREBS, just do the job as you want
    * sudo add-apt-repository ppa:crebs/ppa
    * sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install crebs

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/crebs-wallpaper-slideshow-generator-gets-a-ppa-new-features/

Comment: thanks a ton frnd... this is exactly what I was looking for. not as intelligent as wally but, I'll handle that